# listView.setAdapter doesn't work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a listview called quotesList, and I am trying to use an adapter to put information in it.
Here is my code:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
String[]values={"Android","iOS","Windows Phone","Other Stuff"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,values);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The only error that Eclipse shows is in the *listView.setAdapter(**adapter**)* line. The bold represents where the red squiggly is.

```
Syntax error on token "adapter", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
```

The period after *listView* gives an error as well, but I'm pretty sure its just related to the other error, as its a syntax error.
        Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to clean up your project. Your code is correct. Select Project -> Clean in if you using eclipse as Android Development IDE. This should fix this.

EDIT:
For me this code works in my Eclipse IDE:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotesList);
        String[]values={"Android","iOS","Windows Phone","Other Stuff"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It worked! I think I really just made a very basic mistake - probably so basic it wasn't covered anywhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the third parameter form your ArrayAdapter initialization ie
     `ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem .For me the reason is , declaring the ListView outside  the onCreate() method.